# Rails 3 get raw post data and write it to tmp file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http-post

I'm working on implementing [Ajax-Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) for uploading photos in my Rails 3 app. The documentation says:

> 1. For IE6-8, Opera, older versions of other browsers you get the file as you
>      normally do with regular form-base
>      uploads.
> 2. For browsers which upload file with progress bar, you will need to get the
>      raw post data and write it to the
>      file.

So, how can I receive the raw post data in my controller and write it to a tmp file so my controller can then process it? (In my case the controller is doing some image manipulation and saving to S3.)

Some additional info:

As I'm configured right now the post is passing these parameters:

```
Parameters:
{"authenticity_token"=>"...", "qqfile"=>"IMG_0064.jpg"}
```

... and the CREATE action looks like this:

```
def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new
    @attachment.user = current_user
    @attachment.file = params[:qqfile]
    if @attachment.save!
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :text => '{"success":true}' }
        end
    end
end
```

... but I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: File file name must be set.):
  app/controllers/attachments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Comment: I just released an example of ajax upload in rails 3 + Uploadify here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax . Hope it may help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's because params[:qqfile] isn't a UploadedFile object but a String containing the file name. The content of the file is stored in the body of the request (accessible by using *request.body.read*). Ofcourse, you can't forget backward compatibility so you still have to support UploadedFile.

So before you can process the file in a uniform way you have to catch both cases:

```
def create
  ajax_upload = params[:qqfile].is_a?(String)
  filename = ajax_upload  ? params[:qqfile] : params[:qqfile].original_filename
  extension = filename.split('.').last
  # Creating a temp file
  tmp_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploaded.#{extension}"
  id = 0
  while File.exists?(tmp_file) do
    tmp_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploaded-#{id}.#{extension}"        
    id += 1
  end
  # Save to temp file
  File.open(tmp_file, 'wb') do |f|
    if ajax_upload
      f.write  request.body.read
    else
      f.write params[:qqfile].read
    end
  end
  # Now you can do your own stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great! As a comment, I found (after you set me on the right track) that in my case at least `tmp_file = Tempfile.new(filename)` works equally well while being a little cleaner than your code under the `# Creating a temp file` note. Both ways work fine. Thanks!

Comment: `f.write params[:qqfile].read` - this should be `f.write params[:qqfile].tempfile.read` otherwise no file is stored

Comment: No it shouldn't, UploadedFile#read is a shortcut for UploadedFile#tempfile.read so the code does the same in both cases

Comment: This is a better way to naming the tmp file `id = 0 
    file_template = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploaded-%s.#{extension}"
    tmp_file = file_template % id
    while File.exists?(tmp_file)
      id += 1
      tmp_file = file_template % id
    end`

Answer (score 5):

try it, add lib/qq_file.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'mime/types'

# Usage (paperclip example)
# @asset.data = QqFile.new(params[:qqfile], request)
class QqFile < ::Tempfile

  def initialize(filename, request, tmpdir = Dir::tmpdir)
    @original_filename  = filename
    @request = request

    super Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(filename), tmpdir
    fetch
  end

  def self.parse(*args)
    return args.first unless args.first.is_a?(String)
    new(*args)
  end

  def fetch
    self.write @request.raw_post
    self.rewind
    self
  end

  def original_filename
    @original_filename
  end

  def content_type
    types = MIME::Types.type_for(@request.content_type)
      types.empty? ? @request.content_type : types.first.to_s
  end
end
```

in assets_controller type this:

```
def create
  @asset ||= Asset.new(params[:asset])

  @asset.assetable_type = params[:assetable_type]
  @asset.assetable_id = params[:assetable_id] || 0
  @asset.guid = params[:guid]
  @asset.data = QqFile.parse(params[:qqfile], request)
  @asset.user_id = 0
  @success = @asset.save

  respond_with(@asset) do |format|
    format.html { render :text => "{'success':#{@success}}" }
    format.xml { render :xml => @asset.to_xml }
    format.js { render :text => "{'success':#{@success}}"}
    format.json { render :json => {:success => @success} }
  end
end
```

javascript:

```
var photo_uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
  element: document.getElementById('photo-button'),
  multiple: true,
  action: '/assets',
  allowedExtensions: ['png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg'],
  sizeLimit: 2097152,
  params: {guid: $('#idea_guid').val(), assetable_type: 'Idea', klass: 'Picture', collection: true}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
gem 'rack-raw-upload', :git => 'git://github.com/tb/rack-raw-upload.git'
```

and in config.ru:

```
 require 'rack/raw_upload'
 use Rack::RawUpload
```

and use params[:file] in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating some clutter temp file, you can use StringIO.  See my answer about CarrierWave, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812976/478354