# How to Use 'Ajax Upload' with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax-upload

I'm using this Script http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ to get Ajax upload working with Ruby on Rails

but when i try uploading a file on my controller action I only get this:

```
Parameters: {"qqfile"=>"Foo.png"}
{"qqfile"=>"Foo.png", "action"=>"ul_file", "controller"=>"upload_files"}
```

but i cant use this as a file and do things as

```
thefile = params[:qqfile]

foo = thefile.original_filename.slice(thefile.original_filename.rindex("."), thefile.original_filename.length).downcase
```

what do i need to do to get this script working with Ruby on Rails?

Thanks.

///////// Updated

This is how the JS looks Like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
        element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
        // path to server-side upload script
        action: '/NzzT/upload_files/ul_file'
    });

});
```

Comment: what does the code you are using to create the ajax upload in js look like and is it being called?  you know the new AjaxUpload(...) call?

Comment: You can check my update on the question i added the Javascript Call

Comment: I strongly recommend you use this brand new js plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload I wrote the tutorial in the wiki. Quick and easy

Comment: I'll give it a try because i can't get that 'Ajax Upload' plugin working

Comment: @apneadiving: Checked out the setup wrt the plugin you had suggested , found set up instructions for PHP.. does it suport RoR..? . My case is exceptional in a way.. I am trying to use an old config of Rails 2.0.2 and Ruby 1.8.7.. I actually have even a question posted on this..asking for appropriate ajax upload plugin for this quest..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118753/which-ajax-file-upload-plugin-would-best-suit-my-configuration-of-rails-2-0-2-and

Answer (score 1):

my solution posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704143/rails-3-get-raw-post-data-and-write-it-to-tmp-file/5661377#5661377)

I write QqFile for easy uploader. With paperclip example

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good solution using CarrierWave:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Upload-from-a-string-in-Rails-3
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/KBn2WmrwRAs

The syntax looks like this and works like a charm:

```
file = CarrierwaveStringIO.new(params[:qqfile], request.raw_post)
```