# encoding error with ajax upload (qqfile) and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ajax-upload

I'm trying to get an ajax upload working with rails 3.1.3 and paperclip.

I found this solution to my problem [Rails 3 get raw post data and write it to tmp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704143/rails-3-get-raw-post-data-and-write-it-to-tmp-file/5661377#5661377), but using this, I get an 'encoding `undefined conversion` error `"\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`.

The error occurs at the line `@user.photo = @user.photo = QqFile.parse(params[:qqfile], request)`

I have not edited the code supplied in the previous answer, but I'll include it here so you don't have to switch back and forth.

the gem list paperclip, returns `2.5.2, 2.4.5, 2.3.8`

my controller

```
 def create


    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    @user.photo = QqFile.parse(params[:qqfile], request)
    if @user.save
        return render :json => @user
    else
        return render :json => @user.errors
    end
  end
```

qq_file.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'mime/types'

# Usage (paperclip example)
# @asset.data = QqFile.new(params[:qqfile], request)
class QqFile < ::Tempfile

  def initialize(filename, request, tmpdir = Dir::tmpdir)
    @original_filename  = filename
    @request = request

    super Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(filename), tmpdir
    fetch
  end

  def self.parse(*args)
    return args.first unless args.first.is_a?(String)
    new(*args)
  end

  def fetch
    self.write @request.raw_post
    self.rewind
    self
  end

  def original_filename
    @original_filename
  end

  def content_type
    types = MIME::Types.type_for(@request.content_type)
      types.empty? ? @request.content_type : types.first.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: the error occurs during the upload or in the view ?

Comment: the error occurs during the 'create', at the line `@user.photo`, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an encoding error related to Ruby 1.9.2 (or I believe Ruby 1.9+). 
this github post lead to the answer
https://github.com/lassebunk/webcam_app/issues/1

You must specify `raw_post.force_encoding("UTF-8")` when reading an upload as far as I could tell (I'm not a great programmer).