# Upload File simple way in Ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I searched a lot, I want simplest way to upload file on a directory, not in Database, without Model,without any plugin gems... just want to use controller and View, 
all simple tutorials are old now, and problems with methods, Any expert can tell me??
i have installed Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you.
well I'm gonna leave it there and use paperclip .
this address got some thing . let us know if you find something .

[Rails 3 get raw post data and write it to tmp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704143/rails-3-get-raw-post-data-and-write-it-to-tmp-file)